# Angular2 cli asset folder not compiled automatically when updated

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have created new project using angular-cli.Inside asset folder i have created images folder. After that in app.component.html i have added following line

```
<img src="assets/images/zz.png">
```

i didn't put zz.png in images folder till now, after that i run ng-serve command,

Once appication ran image is not showing.. which is obvious,now i pasted zz.png inside images folder.

My issue is still image is not displaying,i need to stop and re-run ng-serve command again to show image.

so basically i want webpack should compile automatically if i made some changes in assests folder also.

How to acheive this.

Thanks

Comment: what's your `CLI` version? This bug is fixed now [Refer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7521)

Comment: this is my details Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11